# Flutter, open browser and send data with post method

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with flutter in the opening browser.
I want to open a browser and send data to my URL with the post method.
how I can do it?
I'm using url_launcher library for the opening browser too.

Comment: like this?

https://xxxx/yourData

Comment: no. it's the Get method

Comment: This question isn't about Flutter Framework itself. It's about the web page you are opening, which is outside of the flutter application. The way I see it - the web page should have a Javascript code that will submit a hidden form right after the page is loaded.

Comment: whats wrong with doing the POST using flutter? GET POST etc are platform agnostic